# Why setImmediate() not working in expressJS router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to call a expressJS function from view

This is my AJAX :

```
const classify = (name) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: `http://localhost:3000/classify/${name}`,
        success: function (response) {
            //loader.hide()
            if (response.message != undefined) {
                alert(`${response.message}`)
                window.location = response.url
            }
        },
    });
}

$("#classify").on("click", () => {
    loader.show()
    wait.show()
    data.hide();
    const docsName = $("#nameDocs a").text();
    classify(docsName);
});
```

And this is my router :

```
router.get("/classify/:name", (req, res, next) => {
  let result = main(req.params.name);
  console.log("Function in process");

  console.log(`Get ${result}`);

  console.log("Next, send to view");
  setImmediate(() => {
    res.send({ url: "/", message: result });
    console.log("Send success");
  });
});
```

But I'm confused because it's res.send () before the function execution has finished. So I get undefined.

My console shows like this :

```
Function in process
Get undefined
Next, send to view
Send success
GET /classify/pdf_1617994486865_G_PM%20No.%2011%20Tahun%202010.pdf 200 18.193 ms - 11
```

Comment: is `main` function asynchronous function(can you post the main function here) if so then you need to await the main function and then you can use res.send directly without setImmediate

Comment: What `main` is returning?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `setImmediate` and all with `main(…)` returning `undefined`.